# How do I obtain a pointer to an interface?

Tags: c#, interop

I am trying to execute this function:

```
public static int QueryInterface(
    IntPtr pUnk,
    ref Guid iid,
    out IntPtr ppv
)
```

where

```
pUnk
Type: System.IntPtr
The interface to be queried.
```

Basically, Marshal.QueryInterface requests a pointer to a specified interface from a COM object. There is a number of interfaces I would like to query (all from IPersist), so how do I go about obtaining a reference pointer to these interfaces?

Note: IPersistStorage is one of them.

edit (this works):

```
// Use the CLSID to instantiate the COM object using interop.
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid);
Object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Return a pointer to the objects IUnknown interface.
IntPtr pIUnk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(comObj);
IntPtr pInterface;
Int32 result = Marshal.QueryInterface(pIUnk, ref myGuid, out pInterface);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the last line of the remarks section on the [`Marshal.QueryInterface()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.queryinterface.aspx) page.

> The QueryInterface method exposes the [IUnknown::QueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521.aspx) method of a COM object, which attempts to obtain a specific interface pointer.  [...]  To obtain an [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) value that represents a [IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509.aspx) interface pointer, you can call [Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getcominterfaceforobject.aspx), [Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject.aspx), or [Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getidispatchforobject.aspx).

I believe you're looking for the [`Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getcominterfaceforobject.aspx) method.